# slice/array of structs inside a struct

Tags: go, struct

Please consider this go snippet: https://play.golang.org/p/JkMIRwshG5U

My `Service` struct holds:

```
type Service struct {
    ServiceName string
    NodeCount   int
    HeadNode    Node
    Health      bool
}
```

and my Node struct has:

```
type Node struct {
    NodeName  string
    LastHeard int
    Role      bool
    Health    bool
}
```

Suppose if I've 3 nodes for my Service; I'd like the `Service` struct to also have/keep a list of Nodes. Or, a slice of structs since this is Go, and how do I represent this in `Service` struct? (Sorry if this question still comes across ambiguous!)

Comment: Are you asking about basic syntax? A slice type starts with `[]`, so `[]Node` for a slice of `Node`

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JimB pointed out, you'll need a slice of Node objects. Just create a new field within the Service struct to store a slice of Node objects and then append each Node object to that slice of Node objects.

4 minor edits to your code:

```
type Service struct {
    ServiceName string
    NodeCount   int
    HeadNode    Node
    Health      bool
    // include Nodes field as a slice of Node objects
    Nodes       []Node
}

// local variable to hold the slice of Node objects
nodes := []Node{}

// append each Node to the slice of Node objects
nodes = append(nodes, Node1, Node2, Node3)

// include the slice of Node objects to the Service object during initialization
myService := Service{"PotatoServer", 3, Node1, true, nodes}
```

See a working example in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PAz9-4cMkWK)